# How to implement routeGuard in Angular nrwl nx

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular application where I am trying to implement an routxguard, so my http requests are guarded and will be intercepted. But when a page I am trying to route does not do a request the program does not guard the route. I tried to do it with canActivate to my route which looks like this:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('@ditib-emc-medaris/dashboard').then((m) => m.DashboardModule ), canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
  },
```

The UserRouteAccessService class looks like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accountService.identity().pipe(
      map(account => {
        if (account) {
          const authorities = route.data['authorities'];

          if (!authorities || authorities.length === 0 || this.accountService.hasAnyAuthority(authorities)) {
            return true;
          }

          if (isDevMode()) {
            console.error('User has not any of required authorities: ', authorities);
          }
          this.router.navigate(['accessdenied']);
          return false;
        }
        this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(state.url);
        this.router.navigate(['/authtentification']);
        return false;
      })
    );
  }
```

What I want is that if there is no authentication it should redirect back to login:

This is how the login route looks like this:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'authentification'},
      {path: 'authentification', component: LoginComponent}
    ]),
```

Comment: Is `canActivate` actually called or not ?

Comment: Yes it is, if I take it out from my route I can enter it without login, but if I add it, it only shows a empty page, I want to be redirected to the login page

Comment: the guard should return the `UrlTree` (`/authentication`)  instead of `false`. (`false`should only be used to cancel the navigation)